# How to get the index of the barchart label that has been clicked with react-chart js-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have tried the events provided in the documentation as well as some suggestions in some answers but they only work when the bar is clicked not the label. When I click on the label I only get an empty array on "element".

Here is what worked for me so far from clicking on the data bar but doesn't work on label click :

```
setOptions({
  ...
  onClick: function (evt, element) {
    // Get the index clicked:
    const index = element[0]?.index;
  },
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom plugin to achieve this:

```js
const findLabel = (labels, evt) => {
  let found = false;
  let res = null;

  labels.forEach(l => {
    l.labels.forEach(label => {
      if (evt.x > label.x && evt.x < label.x2 && evt.y > label.y && evt.y < label.y2) {
        res = {
          label: label.label,
          index: label.index
        };
        found = true;
      }
    });
  });

  return [found, res];
};

const getLabelHitboxes = (scales) => (Object.values(scales).map((s) => ({
  scaleId: s.id,
  labels: s._labelItems.map((e, i) => ({
    x: e.translation[0] - s._labelSizes.widths[i] / 2,
    x2: e.translation[0] + s._labelSizes.widths[i] / 2,
    y: e.translation[1] - s._labelSizes.heights[i] / 2,
    y2: e.translation[1] + s._labelSizes.heights[i] / 2,
    label: e.label,
    index: i
  }))
})));

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {},
  plugins: [{
    id: 'customHover',
    afterEvent: (chart, event, opts) => {
      const evt = event.event;

      if (evt.type !== 'click') {
        return;
      }

      const [found, labelInfo] = findLabel(getLabelHitboxes(chart.scales), evt);

      if (found) {
        console.log(labelInfo);
      }

    }
  }]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```